# AngularJs 1.6.5 Upgrade - Translate Issue

Tags: angularjs

After upgraded angularjs version from 1.2.8 to 1.6.5 translate not working.

**{{'Please_Select_A_Role' | translate}}**

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working? Are there any errors or is the output not what you expect?

Could you provide more context with your code? For example, what you expect the output to be along with as much of a complete failing test case as you can share

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.